# How do we partition list in Haskell by a separator element of the list?

Tags: haskell

I want to take an Int value and a list that returns a list of lists where the Int value is what separates the values into groups.
Here is an example below:

```hs
partitionBy :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
partitionBy = undefined -- pending implementation
```

Example:

```hs
partitionBy 0 [1,2,3,0,4,0,2,9,1] == [[1,2,3],[4],[2,9,1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming every separator (`sep`) value encountered at the start or end, as well as in succession would create an empty list, here's what I came up with:

```hs
partitionBy :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
partitionBy sep l = partitionByAux l []
  where
    partitionByAux (h : t) acc | sep == h = acc : partitionByAux t []
    partitionByAux (h : t) acc = partitionByAux t (acc `snoc` h)
    partitionByAux [] acc = [acc] 

> partitionBy 0 [1,2,3,0,4,0,2,9,1]
[[1,2,3],[4],[2,9,1]]

> partitionBy 0 [0,1,2,3,0,4,0,2,9,1,0]
[[],[1,2,3],[4],[2,9,1],[]]

> partitionBy 0 [1,2,3,0,4,0,0,0,2,9,1]
[[1,2,3],[4],[],[],[2,9,1]]
```

**Edit:**

the function `snoc` is imported from the module `Data.List.Extra`, and what it does is append an element to the end of a list. Alternatively, you can write the said function like this:

```hs
snoc :: [a] -> a -> [a]
snoc [] a = [a]
snoc (h : t) a = h : t `snoc` a
```

**Update:**

Applied suggested modifications by @WillNess to `partitionByAux` for faster execution:

```hs
partitionByAux (h : t) acc | sep == h = reverse acc : partitionByAux t []
partitionByAux (h : t) acc = partitionByAux t (h : acc)
partitionByAux [] acc = [reverse acc]
```

Comment: it's better to have `(h : acc)` instead of the ``(acc `snoc` h)``, to go with `| sep == h = reverse acc : partitionByAux t []`.

Comment: @WillNess Correct! ```[acc]``` also has to be changed to ```[reverse acc]```

Comment: BTW you're reimplementing the functionality of `span` coupled with `unfoldr`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Data.List.Split`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.5/docs/Data-List-Split.html) module provides the [`splitOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.5/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitOn) function which almost exactly does what you want. The only difference is that instead of a single item it takes a whole sublist to split on:

```hs
import Data.List.Split

splitOn [0] [1,2,3,0,4,0,2,9,1] -- evaluates to [[1,2,3],[4],[2,9,1]]
```

As for your `partitionBy` function using a single item, just wrap that argument into a list:

```hs
partitionBy x = splitOn [x]

partitionBy 0 [1,2,3,0,4,0,2,9,1] == [[1,2,3],[4],[2,9,1]] -- True
```