# How to find length of lists in lists in haskell?

Tags: haskell

```hs
snoc :: [a] -> a -> [a]
snoc [] a = [a]
snoc (h : t) a = h : t `snoc` a

lsplit :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
lsplit sep l = lsplit l []
  where
    lsplit (h : t) acc | sep ==  h = acc : lsplit t []
    lsplit (h : t) acc = lsplit t (acc `snoc` h)
    lsplit [] acc = [acc]
```

This is my code and given below is an example of the running of my code :

```
> lsplit 0 [1,2,3,0,4,5]
[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

I need to find the length of the lists in lists. for example,
the length of the lists in lists would be [3,2] for the above code.
How could I do this in Haskell?

Comment: The code you posted does not have anything (apparent) to do with the problem you describe. Post code for what you _attempted yourself to solve the problem_.

Comment: This is the code I attempted myself

Comment: Then it was quite frankly a horrible attempt. Why don't you start with something that has at least a matching signature, such as `[[a]] -> Int`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: this looks like a near-verbatim copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65282146/67579 which solves a sub-problem.

Answer (score 1):

`map` the `length` function onto it:

```hs
> map length [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
[3, 2]
```

Comment: How do I add that in the function mate?

Comment: Because I need it to return just the length and not the separated values

Comment: Then just literally apply it to the return value of the function: `lsplit sep l = map length $ lsplit l []`.